# How to change the color of a button in Kotlin for a second and then change it back?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to change the background color of a button in Android Studio for one second when it is clicked, then change it back to it's old color.

My current code is this

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            Thread.sleep(1_000)
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
```

Which doesn't change the color at all. From some other experimenting I've found it does wait a second before executing the second setBackgroundColor, but it doesn't change it the first time. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent
documention about motion event. You can use Motion event to solve this problem here is example code

```
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        return false;
    }

 });
```

Comment: This is the solution for changing the color when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        Thread.sleep(1_000)
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
    }
}
```